# What permissions one needs to run chmod, chown command on a folder/item?

Tags: linux, sudo, chmod, chown

I've always been running chmod/chown commands as a sudo user. But today I wondered if I don't use `sudo`, what permissions do I need to actually execute `chmod/chown` command on a folder/file? I've tried googling the question, but nothing popped up that answers specifically this question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On Linux:

**chown**: "Only a privileged process (Linux: one with the `CAP_CHOWN` capability) may change the owner of a file." [(Source: chown(2))](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chown)  The easy way to be such a process is to be run by `root`.  See [`explain_chown`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_chown) for help finding out why a particular `chown` failed.  See [`capabilities`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) for ways to give processes that capability other than running as `root`.

**chmod**: The file's owner or `root` can change permissions, plus other processes with the `CAP_FOWNER` capability.  [(Source)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chmod)

**chgrp**: "The owner of a file may change the group of the file to any group of which that owner is a member. A privileged process (Linux: with CAP_CHOWN) may change the group arbitrarily." [(chown(2))](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chown)

Comment: Linux started to implement capabilities around 2004, but the related POSIX proposal was withdrawn in 1997 already. If you are on a modern OS like Solaris, there is `PRIV_FILE_CHOWN` to chown all local files and `PRIV_FILE_CHOWN_SELF`to chown local files owned by you. BTW: An OS that permits to chown remote files from NFS  can be seen as a secutiry risk. On HP-UX, any regular user can chown his files and this is seen as a secutrity risk as well.

Comment: P.S. the capability POSIX proposal was withdrawn because it only handles the privileges between a regular user and the historical root user. Solaris has twice as many fine grained privileges as Linux and permits to remove privileges like e.g. fork() and exec().

Comment: Note that on Linux, when not privileged, you can `chown` the files you own, but only the gid part (to any of the groups you're a member of). I can do `chown stephane:other-group myfile` (or `chown :other-group`) as long as I'm member of `other-group`.

Comment: What about `chgrp` command? Can you please add explanation for that?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thanks, based on your answer I assume that an owner can successfuly run `chgrp` without being privileged user?

Comment: @Maximus yes.  Updated - it was on the already-linked page ;)